# redis pub sub not working inside rest api

Tags: express, redis

I want to use redis pub sub mechanism inside REST api in express framework.Whenever I wrote the subscribe event outside the rest api it's working fine

```
module.exports = async function (app) {
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
await client.connect();

const subscriber = client.duplicate();
await subscriber.connect();

app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('---- inside ----')
    await client.publish('request', 'request-message');
    
    res.json({value:"Ok"})
});
await subscriber.subscribe('response', (message) => {
    console.log(message); // 'message'
    // subscriber.unsubscribe('response');
    // res.json({value:message})
});
}
```

But if I add the subscribe event inside the Rest Api, then It's not working.

```
module.exports = async function (app) {
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
await client.connect();

const subscriber = client.duplicate();
await subscriber.connect();

app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('---- inside ----')
    await client.publish('request', 'request-message');
    await subscriber.subscribe('response', (message) => {
        console.log(message); // 'message'
        // subscriber.unsubscribe('response');
        res.json({value:message})
    });
});
}
```

Using pub-sub mechanism I want to connect other servers.But If I add the subscribe event outside the rest api,then I can't send the response to the client.How to achive this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis PUB/SUB is a fire and forget mecanism so, in the second code snippet you gave, the message is already forgotten when your client subscribes. So you must subscribe before to publish.

```
module.exports = async function (app) {
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
await client.connect();

const subscriber = client.duplicate();
await subscriber.connect();

app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('---- inside ----')
    await subscriber.subscribe('response', (message) => {
        console.log(message); // 'message'
        subscriber.unsubscribe('response');
        res.json({value:message})
    });
    await client.publish('request', 'request-message');
});
}
```

Comment: For first api hit..it's working fine but after that it's throwing error. `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` .

Comment: @Subham I think the problem come from the fact that you are still subscribed to the channel, so any ```"response"``` event will trigger the callback and try ```res.json({value:message})```, which has already been executed, hence, ```you cannot set headers after they are sent to the client```. You should unsubscribe

Comment: after unsubcribe it , before `res.json({value:message})` it's working fine.